# Creating a Mallocate Array Function in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a project where I create several dynamic 2-dimensional arrays of integers in C.

I am trying to reduce redundant code by creating a mallocateArray function. I can get it to work without the function.

The problem is pointers can be a nuisance and for some reason I just get a seg fault when I try and use this method:

heres what I got:

```
     void mallocateArray(int ***array, int *row, int *col){
     //allocate storage for the array of ints:
         *array = (int**)malloc(*row * sizeof(int *));
         int i;
         for (i = 0; i < *row; i++){
            *array[i] = (int*)malloc(*col * sizeof(int));
         }
     }
```

here is how my arrays are defined:

```
     int **matrix1,
     int row = 2
     int col = 3

     mallocateArray(&matrix1, &row, &col);
```

when I run it, I get a seg fault.
So currently I just do not use the method and deal with the redundancy.
I have tried messing around with the pointers, by dereferencing, etc but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I was hoping you guys could help me out.

heres an example of code in my main method that works:

```
      result = (int**)malloc(row1 * sizeof(int *));
int i;
for (i = 0; i < row1; i++){
    result[i] = (int*)malloc(col2 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: You should start by simplifying your code by passing `row` and `col` by value, not by pointer.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: The object that you are allocating here is not a two dimensional array. Yes, you can use the `[][]` syntax to access it, but it is nonetheless different from an array declared with `int [][]`. It is often called a "jagged array" or a "ragged array".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close.  Just missing some parentheses.  This line:

```
*array[i] = (int*)malloc(*col * sizeof(int));
```

Should be:

```
(*array)[i] = malloc(*col * sizeof(int));
```

Watch out for those order of operations!  I took out your unnecessary cast, too.

Your function would be less complicated-looking if you just passed `row` and `col` by value.  Example:

```
void mallocateArray(int ***array, int row, int col)
{
    *array = malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
       (*array)[i] = malloc(col * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

Comment: His function would be a *lot* less complicated if he returned an `int **` instead of accepting an `int ***`.

Comment: thank you so much! yeah i did notice I had some redundant pointers for the row and col... definitely coding way too much C today but I am definitely getting a lot better with pointers so thanks a bunch

Answer (score 4):

You are allocating arrays of arrays. Here's a fun pro-tip - you can condense a 2-d array of known dimensions into a 1-D array! To convert from an (x,y) index into a single dimension index, use the following:
i = (x + y * cols)

Doing so will allow you to generate a single contiguous slab of memory for your array, rather than essentially a list of memory blocks. Try using malloc(sizeof(int) * row * column) and exposing array access as I describe above.

This will reduce the need to dereference columns and provide a (small but present) performance increase.

Comment: Why not allocate it as a 2D array (still a contiguous slab of memory) and be able to use `[][]` to access it still?

Comment: And don't you want `i = (x + y * cols)`?  Assuming `y` is the row index and `x` the column index, that is.

Comment: @CarlNorum I don't think I follow, how can you ensure an entire 2D array is a "contiguous" slab of memory?

Comment: @CarlNorum In your answer above, you are calling malloc more than once, this means you cannot guarantee the subsequent calls give you adjacent memory blocks. And yes, you are right about rows vs cols, will update :-)

Comment: @NikBougalis, `int (*x)[ROWS][COLS] = malloc(ROWS * COLS * sizeof(int))`.  @Ron - I'm not talking about my answer here.  In fact, it's pretty much guaranteed that allocating the way the OP (and my answer) does that the rows *won't* be contiguous.

Comment: @CarlNorum that only works if `ROWS` and `COLS` are macro-defined constants.  In the OP's code, `row` and `col` are both variables.